What protection do Dharmashastras give for a wife who is being harmed by her husband
While I understand the Dharmashastras not liking adultery, allowing a man to discipline his wife for a righteous reason and remarrying while not abandoning his former wife if she is incompatible to raise a family. What if the man has bad habits, cannot support the family, or is harming her? Is she allowed to remarry or seek any protection (divorce) in order to escape her terrible fate. Please answer with authentic sources related to the matter.

As per Nāradasmṛti 12.96:

I've paraphrased the Hindi translation from the above link:

After marriage, if the faultless girl [who has not resorted to another man] discovers a fault with the
husband which was previously not known and after attempting to tolerate it is unable to do so and make a compromise, she is to be
given shelter by her relatives who should find her a suitable groom.
In the absence of any relatives, the girl should be allowed to search for a groom by herself.

As per the Parāśarasmṛti 4.30:

When her husband is missing, or is dead, or has
renounced the world, or is impotent, or has become morally degraded due to sinning (patite), — on any of the said five calamities befalling a woman, law has ordained another husband for her.

Good answer can you find verses from Parasara and Yajnavalkya as well please.

I've updated the answer with a reference from the Parashara smriti. Hope it helps. Didn't get a chance to look at the Yajnavalkya smriti. You can search here: https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/n7/mode/2up

Thank you so much I really appreciate it!! :)

I believe Manu smriti considers abusing a woman or "punishing" without reason a sin, so would that count as moral degradation?

Yes, as hurting any living entity without reason would be treated as himsã (harm or injury).
